# create list of image in different size

Tags: html, css, image

I have many images & I want to create a list of images like this:

[image]

but I generate this list & images not placed correctly:
[image]

Comment: Are all your images square and only the small size or four times that area (plus their padding) ie is it a specific image fitting case or a more general one?

Comment: yes, all images are square and image index 0, 13 and 26 are larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case you could just use a grid with template areas as that gives you good control over positioning.

Essentially your grid will have six columns and six rows.

I'll come back to this shortly and put up a snippet but I thought you might like this idea immediately and look into it in case of use.

UPDATE: here's a snippet using grid. Obviously you'll need to put the right background-image into each div.

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 12vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 12vw);
  grid-gap: 1vw;
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/span 2;
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
}

.container div:nth-child(14) {
  grid-row: 3/ span 2;
  grid-column: 3/ span 2;
}

.container div:nth-child(27) {
  grid-row: 5/ span 2;
  grid-column: 5/ span 2;
}

.container div {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukCns.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to group content into html groups and control them that way. Just depends on the overall application of what you're trying to do. This is also responsive as well.

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
.row .group.count-1,
.row .group.count-4 {
    width: 33%;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .row .group.count-1,
    .row .group.count-4 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.row .group.count-4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row .group.count-1 img,
.row .group.count-4 img {
    margin: 1%;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .row .group.count-1 img,
    .row .group.count-4 img {
        margin: 0 0 1%;
    }
}
.row .group.count-1 img {
    width: 98%;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .row .group.count-1 img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.row .group.count-4 img {
    width: 48%;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .row .group.count-4 img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group count-1">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="group count-4">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="group count-4">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group count-4">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="group count-1">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="group count-4">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group count-4">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="group count-4">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="group count-1">
            <img src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=200&height=200" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is correcr but can you write this code by loop?

Comment: I could, yeah, but where would the fun in that be for you? :) What language are you using?

Comment: I tried but I could not implement it with the loop :( . I use JS and jQuery in Nuxt.js.

Comment: You would need to calculate at certain points when to start/close a new .row for a group of images, when to start/close a group of images, etc. For instance, the first image you need to start a .row to wrap around the next 9 images until you need to close the row. At the 10th image, you need to start a new row and close it again at image 18. Open another at 19 until finally closing at image 27. Inside those rows are different groupings of images. The first is 1,4,4. Second is 4,1,4. Third is 4,4,1. You can use index in the for loop to determine where you are and when to add HTML content.